# Comprehensive conditional probability question

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, conditional-expectation

Bob owns a bakery. It is located on a busy road with a lots of individuals walking by the bakery each day. On average, $\lambda$ individuals go into the bakery per day, the number of individuals entering the bakery follow a Poisson distribution, $N\sim P(\lambda)$. Each person who enters the bakery has a probability $p$  of demanding a loaf of bread. The quantity of loaves demanded, given the number of customers, $N$, follows a Binomial distribution, $X|N \sim Bin(N;\pi)$. Bob sells loaves at a common price of $p$. At dawn, Bob bakes $k$ loaves at a marginal cost of $c$ per loaf and has overhead costs of $F$ per day. At the end of the day, all loaves not sold are thrown away.

**(a) Show that the marginal distribution of the demand for loaves, $X$, is a Poisson distribution, $X\sim P(\theta )$, where $\theta =\pi\lambda$.**

I was able to show this. I included this part for completeness, in case one requires it to solve subsequent parts.

**(b) Sales, $Y$ , are related to demand, $X$, and the daily supply of loaves, $k$, by the relationship $Y = \text{min{$X,k$}}$.  Derive the p.m.f. for $Y$ .**

This implies that sales equal demand if demand is less than the quantity of loaves available, i.e. $Y=X$ when $X\le k-1$ (noting that $k$ is integer valued). But for demand greater than $k$, demand cannot be met, hence sales then equal the total supply of loaves, $k$, i.e. $Y = k$ for $X\ge k$.

I don't know how to use this to find a pmf for $Y$.

**(c) Obtain an expression for the profit random variable, $\Pi (Y|\theta,k)$, as a function of sales, $ Y$, when Bob bakes $k$ loaves, $k$ is a non-negative integer. Hence derive an expression for expected profit when Bob bakes k loaves.**

I believe having the answer to (b) is necessary for solving this part of the question, and all subsequent parts.

**(d) Bob hires you to figure out the number of loaves he should bake at dawn? Provide your answer to Bob's question, indicating what his expected profit will be, and write a short report explaining your answer.**

**To answer the question, assume that Bob is risk neutral and wishes to choose the quantity of loaves to bake to maximise his expected profit, and that $\lambda= 20;   \pi= 0.7; p=5; c=2 \text{ and } F =10$.**

**(e) If Bob adopts your solution for the quantity of loaves to bake, $k$, what is the probability that Bob will sell all his loaves on any given day? What is the probability that Bob will suffer a loss on any given day?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This implies that sales equal demand if demand is less than the quantity of loaves available, i.e. $Y=X$ when $X\le k-1$ (noting that $k$ is integer valued). But for demand greater than $k$, demand cannot be met, hence sales then equal the total supply of loaves, $k$, i.e. $Y = k$ for $X\ge k$.
>
> I don't know how to use this to find a pmf for $Y$.

Sure you do.   What you said in words is the piecewise function

$$\mathsf P(Y=y) ~=~\begin{cases}\mathsf P(X=y) & : 0\leq y\leq k-1\\ \mathsf P(X\geq k) & : y=k\\0 & :\textsf{other } y\end{cases}$$

And you know that $~\mathsf P(X=y)~=~\dfrac{\theta^y~\mathsf e^{-\theta}}{y!}~$ and $~\mathsf P(X\geq k)~=~1-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{\theta^n~\mathsf e^{-\theta}}{n!}$ because $X\sim\mathcal{Pois}(\theta)$

---

Thusly: $\Pi(Y ; \theta, k) ~=~ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{k-1} n~\mathsf P(X=n) ~+~ k~\mathsf P(X\geq k)$

You can now continue.

Comment: Should the k's in the expression after the summand be n's. Seeing that you're summing n's. That is, $\mathsf P(X\geq k)~=~1-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{\theta^n~\mathsf e^{-\theta}}{n!}$.

Comment: @user117498 Indeed.